# Scalability of event hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Can eventhub handle the creation and revocation of millions of publishers per day?

[Publishers policy doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#publisher-policy) doesn't mention anything explicitly:

Answer (score 1):

Since the **creation** of publishers relies heavily on SAS tokens for validation and only sets the partition key internally, there should not be an issue. As far as I know there is no limit to the number of partition keys in Even Hubs.

The **revocation** and **restoration** of publishers requires a management operation API call, which is limited by your throughput units(TUs).

> Each TU entitles the namespace to the following capabilities:
>
> - Up to 1 MB per second of ingress events (events sent into an event hub), but no more than 1000 ingress events, management operations, or control API calls per second.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq

I would try to avoid relying on the planned revocation of publishers, and rather leverage short lifetimes for the publisher SAS tokens because they don't need any management operation when they expire.